# React Native app closing after Razorpay sucessCallBack()

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, razorpay

The entire payment is done properly. Here is the code:
'''

```
    const that = this;
    function makePayment(){
                   var options = {
                    description: 'Bank payment',
                    currency: 'INR',
                    key: 'xxx',
                    amount: that.state.amount_razorpay,
                    name: 'xyz',
                    order_id: that.state.id,
                    prefill: {
                    email: 'xxx@gmail.con',
                    contact: '123',
                    name: 'XYZ'
                        },
                    theme: {color: '#53a20e'}
                    }          
                RazorpayCheckout.open(options,razr_successCallback,razr_errorCallback)                 
    }

    function razr_successCallback(data){
        console.log('success',data.razorpay_payment_id);
        that.setState({razr_Status:"SUCCESS"});
        that.setState({razr_txnId:data.razorpay_payment_id});
       // that.props.navigation.navigate('Secured');


    }

    function razr_errorCallback(data){
        console.log('failure',data);

    }
```

'''

The console at `razr_successCallback()` is giving proper result `{"razorpay_payment_id": "pay_Eby2FPTakKuSrz"}` but the app is exiting immediately without navigation back to the payment page. I even tried `that.props.navigation.navigate('Secured')` but still the payment page is not redirected. What is the problem?

Edit 1 :

'''

```
    RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
                    .then(async data => 
                        await razr_successCallback(data);
                      })
                    .catch(error => {
                      console.log("payment error", error);

                    });


     async function razr_successCallback(data){
        console.log(data);
         that.props.navigation.goBack();   
    }
```

'''

Still facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

This returns a promise, try it this way :

```js
RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
      .then(data => {
              // handle success
             razr_successCallback(data);
            })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("payment error", error);
        
      });
```

in My Case :

```js
const razorpayOpenModal = (razorpay_id, currency) => {
    let options = {
      description: "Credits towards consultation",
      image: images.logo,
      currency: currency,
      order_id: razorpay_id,
      key: RAZOPAY_KEY,
      amount: totalAmount * 100,
      external: {
        wallets: ["paytm"]
      },
      name: "MyApp.jo",
      prefill: {
        email: userFromCtxt && userFromCtxt.email,
        contact: userFromCtxt && userFromCtxt.phone,
        name: userFromCtxt
          ? userFromCtxt.first_name + " " + userFromCtxt.last_name
          : ""
      },
      theme: { color: color.primaryHeaderColor }
    };
    RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
      .then(async data => {
        setPaymentId(data.razorpay_payment_id);
        await setShowModel(true);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("payment error", error)
      });
  };
```

and then on model :

```js
 <MessageModal
        button={true}
        primaryMessage={primaryText}
        secondaryMessage={secondaryText}
        visible={modalVisible}
        transactionResp={transactionResp}
        closeModal={async () => {
          setModalVisible(false);
          await props.navigation.navigate("Home");
        }}
        buttonText={"Continue"}
        image={transactionResp ? images.success : null}
        onPressButton={async () => {
          setModalVisible(false);
          await props.navigation.navigate("Home");
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: I edited the code,, please paste this and try, Same way I am doing, it is working for me. Make your razr_successCallback function async.

Comment: Still the same. No error, even getting the payment id. App is just minimizing and not closing entirely!

Comment: in My case on successful payment, I am generating a order Id and showing a pop up, on Clicking Continue button on Pop Up, it navigates to Home Screen..

Comment: I edited my Answer, as in comments longer text can't be put

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211269/discussion-between-mohit-rai-and-neelam-soni).